# How do you know your mother board support 32ram in one slot

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm using zenith extreme alpha.
it supports up to 128 ram memory.
but I want to make sure I can buy the 32gb ram for one slot 
is there a way to check it supports 32gb ram for one slot?

Comment: It probably supports 8*16GB only.

Comment: is there a way to check? if I buy 32gb it won't work?

Comment: Almost always the maximum per slot is obtained by dividing the maximum total by the number of slots. To confirm you can ask the manufacturer or use the crucial.com configuration tesourses, or others.

Comment: Doesn't your motherboard's manual mention this? It's usually listed even for ordinary PC motherboards.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-Zenith-Extreme-Alpha/specifications/  only total maximum

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual for your motherboard](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketTR4/ROG_ZENITH_EXTREME_ALPHA/E15130_ROG_ZENITH_EXTREME_ALPHA_UM_V2_WEB.pdf):

> **Memory configurations**
>
> You may install 2 GB, 4 GB, 8 GB, and 16 GB unbuffered and non-ECC DDR4 DIMMs into the DIMM sockets.